# Can't display my result in a table - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display my query results on page. However, whenever I run the code although the query is correct it does not display anything. 
Can anyone help? Would be muchly appreciated

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../config1.php");

if(isset($_POST["DailySales"])) {

  $linkid = mysqli_connect(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Could not connect:" . connect_error());

  $sql = "SELECT Retdatetime AS date , sum(rentalrate + overduecharge) AS mny
          FROM frs_FilmRental
          WHERE shopid='2'
          Order BY retdatetime DESC ";

  $result = mysqli_query($linkid, $sql);

  if (!$result)) {
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($linkid));
 }

  echo "<table border  = '1' align='center'>";
  echo "<th> Shop ID 2</th></tr>";

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<h2><center>Shop ID 2 daily sales : </center></h2>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo  $row['mny'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo  $row ['date'];
    echo "</td></tr>";

}
}

?>
```

Comment: well, for one thing you're creating a new `</table>` tag in the loop; place it outside of it.

Comment: make sure `if(isset($_POST["DailySales"]))` that isn't failing; its origin is unknown.

Comment: There's no `$row['date']` it should be `$row['Retdatetime']`

Comment: This would go faster if you post your html form

Comment: Your `{` and `}` don't match.

Comment: Also make sure your query returns something.  Try running it in your phpmyadmin and see

Comment: Had you try to see what "mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))" returns?
with printr(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))

Comment: i have fixed all the mistakes and query works perfectly in my phpmyadmin but its still not displaying my results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
echo  $row ['date'];
```

by

```
 echo  $row ['Retdatetime'];
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand query errors you should use `mysqli_error()` in your code. If there are no errors for executed query, then you can run while loop for it.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../config1.php");

if(isset($_POST["DailySales"])) {

  $linkid = mysqli_connect(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Could not connect:" . connect_error());

  $sql = "SELECT Retdatetime , sum(rentalrate + overduecharge) AS mny
      FROM frs_FilmRental
      WHERE shopid='2'
      Order BY retdatetime DESC ";

  $result = mysqli_query($linkid, $sql);

  if (!$result)) {
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($linkid));
  } else {

  echo "<table border  = '1' align='center'>";
  echo "<tr><th> Shop ID 2</th></tr>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<h2><center>Shop ID 2 daily sales : </center></h2>";
echo "<tr><td>";
echo  $row['mny'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo  $row ['date'];
echo "</td></tr>";


}
echo "</table>";
}
}
?>
```

fixes given in comments also applied

Please copy/paste the error, given by mysqli_error()

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Remove the closing table tag from the loop

Comment: @JayBlanchard I agree your comment, but adding mysql_error() line as a comment was difficult to explain for me. I will update the code, based on given feedback by OP

Comment: You're going to start getting DV's if you don't start explaining your answers better - it is just a fact of lif here on Stack Overflow.